# Click event not supported on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, touch

Is there anyone who know why my JS function does not work on phones ? It work perfectly on desktop but there is no response on Iphone/android phones.
Do I need to add something so it can be understood by phones ?

init-button.js :

```
const initButton = () => {
  const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('#toggleBtn');
  const divList = document.querySelectorAll('.discover');
  toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    divList.forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.add('block');
    });
  });
};
export { initButton };
```

Application.js :

```
import { initButton } from '../components/init-button';
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  AOS.init({
    offset: 100,
    duration: 2000,
  });
  initButton();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try handling touch-specific events, like `"touchend"`. See [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/responsive-mobile-friendly-web-design/touch-events-in-javascript.html) for more details. The following is a simple example borrowed from that article:

```
var theElement = document.getElementById("theElement");

theElement.addEventListener("mouseup", tapOrClick, false);
theElement.addEventListener("touchend", tapOrClick, false);

function tapOrClick(event) {
   //handle tap or click.

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

In particular, notice the use of `event.preventDefault()`. This is necessary when handling multiple event types in order to prevent triggering the same callback twice.